# how to access resources actionbarsherlock jar

Tags: java, android, svn, actionbarsherlock

I put my project up on svn, and i shared 2 projects, mine and actionbarsherlock library

However, every time i checkout the project or update it, the actionbarsherlock library seems to be gone, so i packed it into a jar, and put it into my build path - this way it would always be checked out or updated if needed

However, my manifest had a line that said the following :

```
       android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

how do i access this line  `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">`

from the jar that i packed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use actionbarsherlock as jar. Only as android library project, resources doesn't pack to jar file.
You can look for use maven dependencies.